# Why when i loop a \n in an ' ' char + a number it counts wrong

Tags: java, for-loop, char, newline

Ok, so I have the following code. I know that making a new line in a char makes no sense but what I want to know is why it prints from 10-19 instead of 1-10 as normal. Can someone give me an answer?

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println('\n' + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should count from `0` to `9`. Does that give you any hints, based on the result you're seeing?

Comment: `System.out.println((int) '\n');`

Comment: I tried with 0 and 9 and it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: If you use double quotes instead of single quotes (`System.out.println("\n" + i);`) you will get the result I think you're looking for.

Comment: `println` already prints a new line. What is happening is that you're adding the value of the char '\n' (which happens to be 10) to the integer `i` and printing the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASCII value for `\n` is 10.  The `+` operator is being interpreted as an "add" operand between two numeric values, not as an "append" operation between two Strings.  This is because you are using single quotes, not double quotes.  Single quotes indicate a `char`.

A `char` can be treated as an actual number in Java.  You can check all ASCII values on [this chart](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

[JLS 4.10.1 - Subtyping Among Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1) pretty clearly displays that `char` is a subtype of `int`, if you're in to looking at the in-depth specifications.  There's also [JLS 5.1 - Kinds of Conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1) for details on conversions.

Per Tom Blodget's comment below, it appears that Java actually uses UTF-16 for String literals, as detailed in [the String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [JLS 3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html).  This is likely an important fact to keep in mind, although I have used ASCII values successfully for many years and never encountered a bug or a problem of any kind.

Comment: @FlorinSoldan Glad it helped. :)  Best of luck on your project.

Comment: More appropriately, the Unicode/UTF-16 value for `\n` is 10 (0x000A or the character U+000A, known as linefeed or LF). You can check Unicode values on [this chart](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF). Java doesn't use ASCII but the explanation is correct.

Comment: @TomBlodget Interesting.  Do you have a source saying that Java uses Unicode rather than ASCII?  I've always used the ASCII values, in many applications, perfectly consistently.

Comment: @asteri ["A `String` represents a string in the UTF-16 format."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). ["Programs are written in Unicode."... "Comments, identifiers, and the contents of character and string literals" are not limited to ASCII characters.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html).

Comment: @asteri You may think you are using ASCII but your editor and Java compiler probably think otherwise. What you are probably doing is limiting your source files to contain only characters that could be encoded in ASCII when in fact they are encoded in your platform's default encoding.

Answer (score 5):

`String` concatenation only applies when one of two operands of `+` is a `String` typed value. In this case, you have one `char` and one `int`, no `String` values. As such, you have integer addition. Java applies primitive widening conversion to convert the `char` value `'\n'` to an `int` value, 10. You can then see why it counts from 10 to 19.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Java interprets `'\n'` as ASCII character, which correspond to a integer value of 10 (hex value `0x0A`).

What you can do:

```
System.out.println('\n' + Integer.toString(i));
System.out.println("" + '\n' + i);
System.out.printf("\n %i", i));
System.out.printf("\n" + i));
```

But all ideas are connected to the same idea.

Comment: `System.out.println("" + '\n' + i);` .. wouldn't `System.out.println("\n" + i);` make more sense for this case?

Comment: Yes and no. If we are talking about sense making: Why `println` AND adding '\n'? So, you are right, but actually this question is discussable in general. But I added your suggestion.

Comment: Why, I'm asking why you concatenate a `String` to a `char` instead of using single character String in the first place.